# How to carry out the recursive estimation of a covariance matrix?

Tags: forecasting, covariance, covariance-matrix

This questions is inspired by my reading of "[From Probabilistic Forecasts to Statistical
Scenarios of Short-term Wind Power Production](http://pierrepinson.com/docs/pinsonetal_wpfscenarios_fin.pdf)" by Pinson et al. (2009).

Let $X_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be a random vector. Now, consider the random variables $X_k$ for every *look-ahead* time $k = 1, ..., K$, where $K$ is the maximum forecast horizon. Here, let's assume that $K = 48$. Let $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, ..., X_k)^\top \sim \text{MVN}(\mu_0, \Sigma)$.

For every time $t$, we have a new vector $X_k$ that we define as $X_k^{(t)}$. We can think of this as a new we have a new vector $X \in \mathbb{R}^{48}$ at every hour (In the end of the day, for instance, we'll 24 new vectors). If $X_k$ are column vectors; we can stack them as a row vectors to form a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{i \times 48}$. This way, every column of $M$ is a variable of forecast values valid for a given look-ahead time $k$.

> **Question: how to recursively estimate the covariance matrix $\Sigma_t$
> as new information arrives every hour**?

An unbiased estimator of $\Sigma_t$ is the empirical covariance matrix given by
$$
\Sigma_t = \dfrac{1}{t-1} \sum_{j = 1}^t \mathbf{X}^{(j)} \mathbf{X}^{(j)\top}
$$

However, the authors give a recursive formulation for updating the covariance matrix.

$$
\Sigma_t = \Bigg( \dfrac{t-2}{t-1}\Bigg) \Sigma_{t-1} + \Bigg(\dfrac{1}{t-1}\Bigg) \mathbf{X}^{(t)}\mathbf{X}^{(t)\top}
$$

To see if I had understood the formulation, I tried to calculate the covariance matrix for a small matrix. I coded my example in `R`. If you follow it through, you'll see that I didn't get the right covariance matrix using the recursive formulation. My guess is that I'm not getting the $\mathbf{X}^{(t)}\mathbf{X}^{(t)\top}$ right.

All help will be appreciated.
I took a look at this [CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310680/sequential-recursive-online-calculation-of-sample-covariance-matrix), but it didn't help much. Also, the formulas they have are not exactly the ones I have.

---

```
# Generate a data matrix
set.seed(123)
m = matrix(data = floor(runif(12, 0, 25)), ncol = 3)

# Calculate its variance-covariance matrix
var_cov_m = cov(m)
var_cov_m
#>       [,1]   [,2]  [,3]
#> [1,]  51.0 -20.50 -23.0
#> [2,] -20.5 104.25  -1.5
#> [3,] -23.0  -1.50  33.0

# Here, let's pretend that only the first three rows of m is known. We'll
# call this new matrix y
y = m[1:3,]

# Now, let's calculate the covariance matrix of y
var_cov_y = cov(y)

# Then, if I get this, I can use the recursive formulation to compute the 
# covariance matrix of m with the covariance matrix of y and the new 
# information, in this case, the fourth row. Let's break down the recursive
# formulation in 2 parts: before the plus sign, and after the plus sign.

# First part ======
first_part = ((4-2)/(4-1)) * var_cov_y 

# Second part =====
mean_fourth_row = mean(m[4,])
second_part = (1/(4-1))* (m[4,] - mean_fourth_row) %*% t((m[4,] - mean_fourth_row))

# Now let's add part 1 and 2
update_sigma_4 = first_part + second_part
update_sigma_4
#>           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
#> [1,]  30.48148 -40.1851852 -20.2962963
#> [2,] -40.18519  85.3703704   0.8148148
#> [3,] -20.29630   0.8148148  45.4814815

# Just to check results (Currently, it's not correct)
abs(var_cov_m - update_sigma_4) <= 0.0001 
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#> [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: The formula you quote makes sense only for data assumed to have expectations of zero.  Your code does not generate such data.

Comment: But I did subtract the mean of X from X when I did the recursive update. Shouldn't that account for the non-zero mean?

Comment: The updating formula is not appropriate for that circumstance.  You need a generalization.

Comment: @whuber, would you mind pointing me in the direction of a reference (paper, book, website, or whatnot) that could help me out? Thank you.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=online+covariance.

Comment: Thank you, @whuber